Need to multiply 11.1 with the number of cells that have a value
I need to check 3 cells if they have a value meaning if they are not empty or have 0. Then I need to multiply 11.1 by number of cells that have value. e.g if two of the three cells have a value then the result cell should be 11.1 * 2 = 22.2. if only one cell has a value the result should be 11.1 and if none of the three cells is empty or zero the result should be 33.3.
Thank you.
I did not try anything as I am new to excel

That worked. Thank you

The earlier one will not work try one of these: =MIN(MMULT(N(A1:C1<>{"";0}),{1;1;1}))*11.1 or =(COUNTA(A1:C1) - COUNTIF(A1:C1, 0))*11.1 so i have deleted!
